# In Oracle/SQL how to select rows with same column id but a different value for non-id column

Tags: sql, oracle

In the table below, I want to show every **user_id** that shows up with both a 0 and a 1 in the **is_logged_in** flag.

```
__________________________
| user_id | is_logged_in |
+------------------------+
|    A    |      1       |
+------------------------+
|    B    |      1       |
+------------------------+
|    B    |      0       |
+------------------------+
|    C    |      0       |
+------------------------+
|    D    |      0       |
+------------------------+
|    D    |      1       |
+------------------------+
|    C    |      0       |
+------------------------+
```

Can it be done without a GROUP BY condition? If possible, can you also show me how to query without GROUP BY. Thanks SO.

Result after query:

```
___________
| user_id |
+---------+
|    B    |
+---------+
|    D    |
+---------+
```

Comment: I didn't understand the actual problem, I think you may add more information.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a `group by` condition? Is this part of a homework requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the logic that you are trying to implement?  Why do you want to return B and D but not A or C?

If the question is "show me every `user_id` that shows up with both a 0 and a 1 in the `is_logged_in` flag"

```
select user_id
  from table_name
 group by user_id
having count( distinct is_logged_in ) = 2
```

or

```
select user_id
  from table_name
 where is_logged_in = 0
intersect
select user_id
  from table_name
 where is_logged_in = 1
```

or

```
select a.user_id
  from table_name a,
       table_name b
 where a.rowid != b.rowid
   and a.user_id = b.user_id
   and a.is_logged_in = 0
   and b.is_logged_in = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (user_id = 'B' or user_id = 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct user_id
from table_name a 
inner join table_name b on a.user_id = b user_id
where a.is_logged_in <> b.is_logged_in
```